# My phylogenetic tree stays as a rainbow palette even when the code says a different color sceme

Tags: r, colors, phylogeny

I am making a phylogenetic tree in R using ape, maps, and phytools and have been successful however, no matter what color I change my col to it keeps the tree as the rainbow palette colouration.

```
jpeg("branch3.jpg", width = 1000, height = 1000)

plotBranchbyTrait(tree2, x.num, type = "fan",
                  mode = c("edges","tips","nodes"), 
                  col = c("midnightblue", "deepskyblue", "turquoise1", 
                          "seagreen1", "springgreen3"), 
                  legend = TRUE, xlims = NULL, cex = 1.5, lwd = 0.5)

dev.off()
```

when I use this code I get the follow image:

[image: when I use this code I get the follow image]

Does anyone know why it might be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The colors provided to `plotBrancbyTrait` are passed through the `palette` argument (see the function manual). You can create a palette by using `colorRampPalette` function. For example, in your case:

```
## Creating a customised palette
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("midnightblue", "deepskyblue", "turquoise1", "seagreen1", "springgreen3"))
```

You can then pass it normally to the `plotBranchbyTrait` function as follows:

```
## Plotting branch colors with a personalised palette
plotBranchbyTrait(tree2, x.num, type = "fan",
                  mode = c("edges","tips","nodes"), 
                  palette = my_palette, 
                  legend = TRUE, xlims = NULL, cex = 1.5, lwd = 0.5)
```